# If the ancient one awakens after an investigator dies in the mythos phase, does the player draw a new investigator?

Tags: eldritch-horror

When an investigator is defeated after the ancient one awakens, that player is eliminated. What if the investigator is defeated and the ancient one awakens before the end of the mythos phase?

The ancient one is awake when the investigator would be replaced, but wasn't awake when the investigator was defeated.

In our session, the defeat of the investigator caused the awakening. My reading of the rules is that the player is not eliminated as a result of this. Is there a documentation implying otherwise?

Answer (score 2):

The player draws a new investigator and continues play.

From the FAQ (emphasis mine):

> If an investigator is defeated, the player controlling that investigator chooses a new investigator at the end of the Mythos Phase.
>
> ...
>
> **After the Ancient One has awakened**, when an investigator is defeated or devoured, the player controlling that investigator is eliminated.

Resource guide says the same thing.

This isn't MtG, there isn't a stack.  My understanding of the "wait til the end of the mythos phase to start new guy" rule is to prevent any/all confusion about what actions (and interactions) that person can take.

Comment: I don't completely understand the relevance of the final comment, but if the rule quote is to be read literally as 'if the moment the investigator is defeated occurs after the ancient one already woke, the player is eliminated', then this makes sense to me.

Comment: @Joey So before I knew this rule, we incorrectly put new investigators right into play after they died.  Then we would trade with them, use actions on them, wonder if they got to act in various remaining phases.  IMO, that's why the "wait til the end" rule exists, to prevent all that confusion.  They could have alternatively put "The new investigator cannot be interacted with and does not make dice rolls until the start of the next mythos phase."  But that is more confusing to remember and phrase.  Hope that sheds some light.